# Unable insert in dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a Dynamic Query.

```
   create procedure SP_InsertGroup
   (
     @GroupID nvarchar(50)
    ,@GroupName nvarchar(max)
    ,@ParentId int
    ,@Username nvarchar(50)
   )

   Declare @Insertstring nvarchar(max);
   set @Insertstring='INSERT INTO  GroupDetails

       (GroupID
       ,GroupName
       ,CreatedBy
       ,CreatedOn
       ,ParentID
       ,IsActive
       )
 values('+@GroupID+',
        '''+@GroupName+''',
        '''+@Username+''' ,
        getdate(),
        '+@ParentID+',
        1,
       )'
        execute sp_executesql @query=@Insertstring
```

GroupDetails table accept nulls for all columns...but wen i exec the stored procedure in this way..

```
      exec Sp_insertGroup '1',null,'1',null
```

I am unable to insert.why does this doesnt work in Dyanmic query please help me...

Comment: Ever heard of "SQL Injection"? Why does this have to be dynamic SQL too?

Comment: -1 for not understanding SQL injection and wanting dynamic sql with no regard for consequences

Comment: i knw abt that my need is to implement in DYnamic SQl

Comment: i knw abt that my need is to implement in DYnamic SQl

Answer (score 2):

You don't need dynamic SQL

```
   create procedure SP_InsertGroup
     @GroupID nvarchar(50)
    ,@GroupName nvarchar(max)
    ,@ParentId int
    ,@Username nvarchar(50)
   AS
   INSERT  GroupDetails
       (GroupID
       ,GroupName
       ,CreatedBy
       ,CreatedOn
       ,ParentID
       ,IsActive
       )
    values(@GroupID, @GroupName, @Username, getdate(), @ParentID, 1)
   GO
```

I'd also have defaults for CreatedOn and IsActive on the table

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is that when you are building your dynamic SQL string and some of the elements are null, it makes the whole string null.

To fix it, you need to wrap any nullable elements with `ISNULL(@param, 'null')`.

But don't do this, do what @gbn says.

Comment: The fix should be more sophisticated because of the surrounding quotation marks in two cases. But anyway, I agree with you in that gbn's answer is the way to go.

Comment: @Andriy M - yes you're right.  I was tempted not to include any kind of example solution so as to steer them away from doing it this way.